# Prove that for any real number $a$ there exists a number such that $c^3=a$

Tags: calculus

I want to apply the intermediate-value theorem to prove it.

Let $f(x)=x^3-a$. Since $x^3-a$ is a polynomial, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Now I want to show that $0$ is a number between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ so that I can imply
$$
\exists c : f(c) = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad c^3-a = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad c^3 = a \;.
$$
However, I don’t know how to show that $0$ is a number between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^3-a)=-\infty$ there exists $x_1\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1)=x_1^3-a<0.$ Since  $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x^3-a)=\infty$ there exists $x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_2)=x_2^3-a>0.$ Now, using that $f(x)=x^3-a$ is continuous, we conclude from the intermediate value theorem that there exists $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(c)=0.$

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ as a function of $a$. To simplify the problem, assume that $a>1$. You want $x_1^3<a$ and $x_2^3>a$. Can you think of an $x_1$ and $x_2$ that meet these requirements?

(Or, as mfl says, you can infer the existence of *some* appropriate $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the limiting behavior.)